Bluetooth keyboard connects, but keyboard input does not register
I got this keyboard, which supports up to 3 bluetooth connections and a dongle based connection to switch between.
When using the dongle, it works fine, it gets picked up and keyboard events get registered, but when using the bluetooth connection, I can find two versions TMKB T63 3.0 and TMKB T63 5.0.
I am using blueman, TMKB T63 5.0 fails to connect, but I can connect with TMKB T63 3.0. When connected btmon receives transmissions when I hit the keys, but all the 10 or so different TMKB devices in evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event10: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event11: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event12: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/dev/input/event13: Video Bus
/dev/input/event14: Video Bus
/dev/input/event15: sof-hda-dsp Headphone
/dev/input/event16: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event17: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
/dev/input/event18: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
/dev/input/event19: Beiying TMKB T63
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event20: Beiying TMKB T63
/dev/input/event21: Beiying TMKB T63 Consumer Control
/dev/input/event22: Beiying TMKB T63 System Control
/dev/input/event23: Beiying TMKB T63 Keyboard
/dev/input/event24: Beiying TMKB T63 Mouse
/dev/input/event25: Bluetooth Mouse
/dev/input/event26: Bluetooth Mouse Consumer Control
/dev/input/event3:  Power Button
/dev/input/event4:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event5:  ELAN0525:01 04F3:323F Mouse
/dev/input/event6:  ELAN0525:01 04F3:323F Touchpad
/dev/input/event7:  Acer Wireless Radio Control
/dev/input/event8:  Acer WMI hotkeys
/dev/input/event9:  HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Select the device event number [0-26]: 

do not pickup any events.
